# Read the contents of an entire disk bit by bit in C

Tags: c, winapi

I have tried using DeviceIoControl to get the data into a buffer b about the disk. When I try using something like total = b.cylinders.quadpart * b.trackspercylinders * b.sectorspertrack * b.bytespersector, I end up getting a negetive number in total. Now I don't know how to evaluate the total number of sectors in a disk to run a for loop and use the readfile function to print out the contents.
A code snippet for the same would be very useful.

```
TCHAR cOutputPath0[32000];
char strPath[] = "\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0";
        ExpandEnvironmentStrings((LPCTSTR)strPath, cOutputPath0, (sizeof(cOutputPath0) / sizeof(*cOutputPath0)));

        HANDLE drive = CreateFile(cOutputPath0, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

        DWORD br = 0;
        DISK_GEOMETRY dg;

        DeviceIoControl(drive, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY, 0, 0, &dg, sizeof(dg), &br, 0);

            TCHAR sectorData[32000];

            LARGE_INTEGER t1 = dg.Cylinders;
            printf("%d\n", t1.QuadPart);
            int t2 = dg.TracksPerCylinder;
            printf("%d\n", t2);
            int t3 = dg.SectorsPerTrack;
            printf("%d\n", t2);
            int t4 = dg.BytesPerSector;
            printf("%d\n", t2);

            unsigned long long total = t1.QuadPart*t2*t3*t4;
            unsigned long long j;

            printf("%d", total);

            for (j = 0; j < total; j++) {
                LARGE_INTEGER pos;
                pos.QuadPart = j* dg.BytesPerSector;
                SetFilePointerEx(drive, pos, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
                if (ReadFile(drive, sectorData, dg.BytesPerSector, &br, NULL) && br == dg.BytesPerSector) {
                    printf("%s", sectorData);
                }

            }
```

Does this code seem right to do it? Because I still seem to get a negetive number!

Comment: Modern disks are big and likely to cause overflow in this 32-bit calculation.  Cast to (unsigned long long) to get a 64-bit multiplication.

Comment: You can only read bytes, not bits.  You’re probably suffering from integer overflow. Without enough code to form an MCVE ([MCVE]), we cannot tell for sure.

Comment: Don't know about your computer, but this one has a disk that contains 3.000.000.000.000 bytes. Are you sure you want to display all of those?

Comment: Yes, willing to display all of them!

Comment: You are printing `total` with `%d` which does not match the actual data type.

Comment: Yes I just fixed that. Apart from that, is the program logically correct?

Comment: Your question was why you are getting a negative number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateFile` could easily fail in this case, either because admin access is required or because `"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"` is the wrong disk. Basic error check is strongly recommended for any file operation.

Run the program with admin access, and make sure `"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"` is the right disk (it's not always `C:\`)

`SetFilePointerEx` is not required if you are reading the file in sequence. The file pointer automatically moves ahead after each `ReadFile`

```
#define UNICODE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE handle = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0",
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, NULL);

    if(handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        //wrong disk, or admin access required
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        printf("!CreateFile, GetLastError: %d\n", err);
        CloseHandle(handle);
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD br = 0;
    DISK_GEOMETRY dg;
    if(!DeviceIoControl(handle, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY,
        0, 0, &dg, sizeof(dg), &br, 0))
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        printf("!DeviceIoControl, GetLastError: %d\n", err);
        return 0;
    }

    LARGE_INTEGER t1 = dg.Cylinders;
    int t2 = dg.TracksPerCylinder;
    int t3 = dg.SectorsPerTrack;
    int t4 = dg.BytesPerSector;
    unsigned long long total = t1.QuadPart*t2*t3*t4;

    printf("%lld\n", t1.QuadPart);
    printf("%d\n", t2);
    printf("%d\n", t3);
    printf("%d\n", t4);
    printf("%llu\n", total);

    //setup a counter
    long long i = 0;

    int bufsize = dg.BytesPerSector;
    char *buf = malloc(bufsize);
    while(ReadFile(handle, buf, bufsize, &br, NULL))
    {
        if(!br)
            break;

        //print update
        if((i % 1000) == 0)
            printf("%.2f Mb\n", (double)i * bufsize / 1000000.0f);
        i++;
    }

    free(buf);
    CloseHandle(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the above reads one sector at a time. This is useful if you want to examine each sector separately, but it's also slow.

The method below shows reading 100 sectors at a time. This is faster but a little more complicated because it includes sectors which are not necessarily related. To examine, you can break `buf` in to different sectors.

```
//read N number of dg.BytesPerSector for each pass
int N = 100;
int bufsize = dg.BytesPerSector * N;
char *buf = malloc(bufsize);
while(ReadFile(handle, buf, bufsize, &br, NULL))
{
    if(!br)
        break;

    //print update
    if((i % 1000) == 0)
        printf("%.2f Mb\n", (double)i * bufsize / 1000000.0f);
    i++;

    //look for *.cpp files which have the string `#include` in them:
    //buf includes N sectors
    //look for `#include` in each sector and print the first 100 characters
    for(int j = 0; j < N * dg.BytesPerSector; j += dg.BytesPerSector)
        if(strstr(&buf[j], "#include"))
            printf("%.100s ...\n", &buf[j]);
}
```

---

Side note: you are using `(LPCTSTR)strPath` which suggests the program is compiled with `UNICODE` defined (as it should be) but you use ANSI string as argument, then using cast to hide the error. Just use Unicode for all WinAPI functions. Set compiler warning to highest level, and don't use cast unless you are absolutely sure. Also `ExpandEnvironmentStrings` is for other strings like `"%windir%"`.

Comment: Perfect. Only 2 questions though. 1. Without the ExpandEnvironmentVariables function, I'm unable to locate any PhysicalDrive0 and createfile function fails. 2. Shouldn't i be unsigned long long instead of just long long?

Comment: Also 1 more question. You said I don't need to use setPointerex function. So even if I read from a logical volume such as C: or D: sequentially instead of PhysicalDrive. Do I need to use it then?

Comment: `ExpandEnvironmentVariables` doesn't do anything here. Is Unicode defined in your program? Use `CreateFileW(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", ...)` or `CreateFileW(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive1", ...)` (note the `W` at the end) - You are reading sequentially in this case, so don't worry about `SetPointerEx` for now.

Comment: Unicode isn't defined in my program but I guess the visual studio settings are set to use Unicode character set. Also I'm planning to use a string such as str for the - PhysicalDrive0. So in createfilew, do I need to use (Lstr,....)?

Comment: Also why is the readsize dg.bytespersector * 100? Shouldn't it be equal to dg.bytespersector?

Comment: That size should be a multiple of `BytesPerSector`. I multiplied by 100 to run faster. You can just set it to one `BytesPerSector`, it might be easier - See edited version on how to handle the buffer when buffer includes multiple sectors.

Comment: In the code above, you wrote CreateFile instead of CreateFileW. Was that intended?

Comment: `CreateFile` is a macro. If Unicode is not defined, it changes to `CreateFileA("ANSI", ...)` If Unicode is defined, it changes to `CreateFileW(L"Unicode", ...)`. It's the same with other Windows functions which have string input/output. `TCHAR` is also a macro. It is `char`/`wchar_t` depending on Unicode. Here I have put `#define UNICODE`, so both `CreateFile` and `CreateFileW` are the same - More info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

(Edit: In the snipped that you've provided in an edit, it turned out that the actual type of the variable is correct, but the issue is in output — you're printing `long long` values with `%d`, which prints a `signed int`. For `unsigned long long`, you should use `%llu`, and for `signed long long`, it's `%lld`.)

Your `total` variable appears to be a `signed int`, which, on your configuration — apparently a Windows x86-32 or x86-64 PC — is 32 bit wide, and thus can store values up to 2147483647 (2³¹−1), or 2 GB minus one byte.

You should change it to `unsigned long long` (or `uint64_t` from `stdint.h`).

Also note that multiplying an `int` by an `int` results in an `int` — so if you expect the result of the multiplication to be bigger than 2³¹−1, at least one of the two multiplicands must be `long long`.

In this specific case, `b.Cylinders.QuadPart` is already a `long long` (not `unsigned`, though, but there are no disks with a capacity of over 9 exabytes, at least in 2018), so the result of the multiplication will be a `long long` too, but generally you should perform large integer multiplication like `unsigned long long total = ((unsigned long long) uintA) * uintB * uintC * uintD`.